# How to detect BodyTag web element in Ranorex path using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ranorex

I used Ranorex.TryFindSingle() method to look for specific bodytag path but failed to detect it.

```vb
 Dim WebDocument As WebDocument
 Dim eReturnElement As Element = Nothing
 Dim bElementPath As Boolean = False

  WebDocument = "/dom[@domain=abc.com]"
  bElementPath = WebDocument.TryFindSingle(".//div[#'tabstripAbcEnter-4']/div/div[2]/?/?/table//iframe[@src='javascript:""']/body", eReturnElement)
```

Failed to detect the path.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the item not being found instantly. If you are sure the element is able to be found using this path (you can use Ranorex Spy to verify) then I would suggest you utilize a timeout of 1min to help see if it just needs more time:

```
 Dim WebDocument As WebDocument
 Dim eReturnElement As Element = Nothing
 Dim bElementPath As Boolean = False
 Dim timeout As New Duration(60000)

  WebDocument = "/dom[@domain=abc.com]"
  bElementPath = WebDocument.TryFindSingle(".//div[#'tabstripAbcEnter-4']/div/div[2]/?/?/table//iframe[@src='javascript:""']/body", timeout, eReturnElement)
```

Also, since the element is in a iframe, if you are using Google Chrome you may need to add the flag "--disable-web-security" to allow cross domain scripting. If Spy is unable to see elements inside the iframe this could be the reason.